# SpringApplicationBuilder to combine small SpringBoot applications (modular Monolith)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, module, dependencies

I am trying to build a "Main" SpringBoot application which shall be composed out of many small independent SpringBoot Applications. The main application talks with each of the small SpringBoot applications to query data or to modify data. Each of the small application fulfills a certain domain. For example a dependency / SpringBoot Application for user management, mail transfer, product management, order fulfilling. Each of the small application uses an own database which is separated from the others.

I've added the small applications as dependency to my main application. What I'm now facing is the problem or the fact that the main instantiates all beans from the dependency applications. I know, this is how SpringBoot works. The problem is that there are some components or classes in each dependency with the same name. So running the application just crashes because there are beans with the same name which is correct. Further the main tries to instantiate a Hikari DB connection but should not have any db connection. I think that is because the other applications have a db connection. Therefore, the main also tries to build up a db connection.

The idea behind this is to build a modular monolith so in future one or more of the dependencies can be replaced by a microservice. Currently, building a microservice architecture is not required  and not claimed. Therefore, I would like to build a modular monolith architecture.

Is there a way that each of the Spring Boot application just uses their own Beans and the main application can just invoke a certain interface / API of the others? Just like the other services expose a REST API but without exposing a REST API.

Would be the `SpringBootApplicationBuilder` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html) using child / siblings a way to achieve my goal? Or do I miss something and there is no way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

In case of Spring Boot's children - there will be potential conflicts in resources and bindings: you'll not be able to bind 2 servlet container instances to same port anyway, so be required to separate them.

Think will be better to use single Spring Boot application and use dedicated classes with @Configuration annotation per child 'application' as starting point:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeModuleConfig {

@Bean
public Bean myModuleBean() {}

}
```

To avoid global scan ,you can play with @ComponentScan include/exclude filters:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Comment: The "child" or "dependency" applications do not expose any endpoint, so they do not run on any port. They are just contain of @Component @Service and @Repository classes. 

I want to achieve that main SpringBoot application just calls `mydependencyServiceApi.getUser(userId)` of my "micro" SpringBoot application and everything is handled in the context of the micro SpringBoot application. If I exclude for example the @Repository from "micro" SpringBoot application the instantiation of the service will fail as there is no Repository bean. I hope my goal description is clear. Otherwise ask pls

Comment: 2 ways: 1) use mock beans - when module provides 'mydependencyServiceApi' is not loaded - there is a default mock bean with same name and methods, but with empty logic.  Works great for gateways, senders, pushers - all kind of logic that typically have 1-2 input methods and complicated processing inside. 2) use dedicated  setup for repositories too: @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= "com.xxx.module1.repository") in each module

Comment: I think I have expressed myself incorrectly. I excluded in main the repository package of micro. Now when everything gets instantiated Sprint failed because service of micro is missing the repository of micro. Which makes sense. 

But is it possible to use different databases for each module / dependency micro application? I am scared that when I have 5 micro applications with 5 independent databases they somehow get mixed up. For example micro1 uses database configured in micro2 which will not work as schema does not match

Comment: ... or is there another way to achieve my goal

Comment: If you need isolation - try  to use OSGi container https://felix.apache.org/ , even ordinary JEE / Servlet container could help: just pack your 'micro' applications into separate WARs and deploy all together to Apache Tomcat/JBoss Wildfly/Glassfish/whatever. But Spring Boot is all about single application and shared state.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I thought creating a jar and use it as dependency would be enough. A single application was the goal. So to get it working my way I have to keep names of beans unique and also use different configuration parameter names as the will all be merged into one which also means that all database urls in moudle1 module2 and so on with the same name will be merged into one which

Comment: deploying each micro application as separate WAR would be such like microservices. That means each "micro" application will run on the same machine but on different ports and exposing a REST API. Then each micro application will run in his own ApplicationContext which then will not interfere with the other ApplicationContext of the other services. Otherwise, I'll get the problem that the ApplicationContext will get all Repositories of each Module and then I have the problem that there is more than one DataSource bean which will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to separate modules using context hierarchy, but of course, as @Alex said you must take care of proper component scanning:

```java
public class Bootstrap {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bootstrap.class);

    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "spring.config.location=classpath:/config/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplicationBuilder parentBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(CtxParent.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE);

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context =
            parentBuilder.parent(CtxParent.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET)
                .properties("spring.config.name=application",CONFIG_LOCATION).run(args);
            parentBuilder.child(CtxModuleOne.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE) // whatever
                .properties("spring.config.name=module-one",CONFIG_LOCATION).run(args);
            parentBuilder.sibling(CtxModuleTwo.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE) // whatever
                .properties("spring.config.name=module-two",CONFIG_LOCATION).run(args);

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I thought it would be much easier without the need to do much configuration. If I do it that way will my Parent be able to use the Service of my ModuleOne? Maybe my idea is not possible to realize but I thought it would just be develop x modules, aggregate them using dependencies in one main WebApp and that's good. To point out: The small applications do not expose any web API. The invoking to a dependency should happen without any web layer. Just localy.

Comment: As of my knowledge, by default - the child sees the parent, not vice-versa. They only share the environment.

Comment: Okay. I’ll have to try that out by using the hierarchy. 
Damn I really thought it is much easier. Seems to be no so easy to build an composed application with one main application.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore my first paragraph (For the problem of bean instanciation, if you have @ComponentScan in your root application, you could try to remove it and add @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com....") to each individual module's exposed service or controller. The main application should not see everything inside the child modules. The components (beans) stay only in the contexts of each module whilst the main application interacts with each module's API.)

For the database issue, implement separate configurations for each module. Bellow is an example of a module's database configuration in my application:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.path.to.academy.persistency",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "academyEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "academyTransactionManager"
)
public class PersistenceAcademyAutoConfig {

    @Autowired
    ExternalConfigurations externalConfigurations;

    @Autowired
    AcademyExternalConfigurations academyExternalConfigurations;

    public PersistenceAcademyAutoConfig(
    ) {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean academyEntityManager() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(academyDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.path.to.academy.domain");

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", externalConfigurations.getHibernateDdl());
        properties.put("javax.persistence.create-database-schemas", externalConfigurations.getDbSchemaCreationDirective());
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", externalConfigurations.getHibernateDialect());
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", externalConfigurations.getShowSql());

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource academyDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url(academyExternalConfigurations.getDbUrl());
        dataSourceBuilder.username(externalConfigurations.getDbUser());
        dataSourceBuilder.password(externalConfigurations.getDbPassword());
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(externalConfigurations.getDbDriverClassName());
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager academyTransactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(academyEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I've already worked out that DB and Flyway prob. If I remove component scan how do I get the API to my root application? Sure using REST Communication would work out, but then I do not need the hard dependency between root -> module. Further excluding packagescan would lead to the problem that for example module1 @ Service can't get autowired because in @ Service used @ Repository could not be autowired

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion was misleading. I was thinking about running the modules as separate applications with independent contexts.

Comment: No problem! @Eliaquim - I think that's the only approach that works. I've tried to use different modules with their own context but that seems not possible.

Comment: Yes, that's more like microservices realm. Even if you do run them in separate, independent contexts, them you would have a hard time dealing with sessions and user management amongst the contexts. 

There is this https://gitlab.com/SpaceTrucker/modular-spring-contexts , but it's not gaining traction, by the numbers. I tried and gave up. Went with modular monolith, one context.